# How to Build ElasticSearch Docs offline

Tags: elasticsearch, asciidoc

I might have no Internet for some time and yet I need to use ES docs. How can I view them offline? So far I have tried...

1. `git clone https://github.com/elastic/docs.git`
2. `cd docs/ && ./build_docs --doc README.asciidoc --open`

Great, now I see a welcome page. But how do I get the rest of the docs? The README tells me to specify path/to/index.asciidoc but he only .asciidoc files in the repo seem to be README.asciidoc and Versions.asciidoc? Where is the rest? --all gives me a `Command '['ssh-add', '-L']' returned non-zero exit status 1`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running

```
build_docs --all
```

from https://github.com/elastic/docs#for-the-website

Comment: Yes I have. I mentioned that in my original post with the error message that it produced.

Comment: The readme says `Note If you do not have authority to access all of the necessary repositories, an error occurs during the cloning phase.` but it doesn't say anything about how to solve this problem (eg ignore repository paths that you have no access to)